# Reordering half closed intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider family  $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ of disjoint intervals $I_j=(a_j,b_j]$  such that $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty I_j=(a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}.$

**Question:** Can I claim that it always exists a way to reindex the intervals 
$I_j$ s.t $\bigcup_{j=1}^nI_j$ is an interval contained in $(a,b]$?

I'm trying to use compacticity properties of $\mathbb{R}$ but I can't do it yet...

Comment: Can you revisit your indices? $\bigcup_{j=1}^nI_n$ is probably not what you were willing to write.

Comment: Thanks for the  advertisement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a way does not always exist. Let 
$$
I_n=\begin{cases}
(\,(\frac12)^{k+1},(\frac12)^k] & n=2k \text{ is even}\\
(\,(\frac12)^{k+1}+\frac12,(\frac12)^k+\frac12] & n=2k-1 \text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$

The union of $I_1,I_2,I_3,\dots$ is $(0,1]$, where the even intervals are a partition of $(0,1/2]$ and the odd intervals are a partition of $(1/2,1]$. Two intervals $I_i$ and $I_j$ can only be adjacent if both $i$ and $j$ are both even or both odd. Therefore, in a reordering of $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ so that the union of any initial segment is an interval, the parity of each index would have to match the parity of the first index, which means that not every interval appears in the reordering.